# How to reset default file opening? (ubuntu tweak failed)

Tags: gedit, default-programs, ubuntu-tweak

For some reason my install decided to open all text files with a hex editor (okteta) instead of gedit. When I go into the properties window for the file type, remove okteta and click apply, okteta immediately reappears at the top of the list.

So I tried running

```
apt-get purge okteta
```

In the hopes that that would clear out whatever file is doing this, but it hasn't. Now I just get an error whenever I double click a text file.

Next I tried ubuntu-tweak, and okteta isn't on the list of applications used to open files at all.

Is there a file I can delete that will force reconfiguration?

Answer (score 0):

Open the properties window of the target file. You'll see this...

[image]

Select the `Open With` tab, and find `Text Editor` in the list of applications, highlight it, and click the `Set as default` button.

Comment: Please remember to vote/accept my answer if it was helpful.

Comment: I did that originally, that's in the first sentence of my answer.  After setting it it goes back to how it was.   Presumably the file it's changing got changed to read only somehow.

Comment: No, you said "remove okteta and click apply". That's not the same as selecting `Text Editor` and clicking `Set as default`. Re-read my instructions carefully.

Comment: it's the closest equivalent when using KDE though.

Comment: You might want to edit your question and add that information.